# How many levels are there for Steam Trading Card badges?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

With the new Steam Trading Cards, I decided to craft the badge for *CS:GO*. I got this:

[image: CS:GO Level 1 Badge - Grenade Spammer]

I then noticed that this is only a level 1 badge, and there was a level 2 badge to get. So I crafted it too:

[image: CS:GO Level 2 Badge - Bullet Spray]

Now it says there's a level 3 badge to get next. How many levels are there in total?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## All games have:

- A max of **5** levels for the regular badge.
- A max of **1** level for the Foil badge.

A few examples:

- [Counter-Strike: Global Offensive](http://www.steamcardexchange.net/index.php?gamepage-appid-730)
- [Dota 2](http://www.steamcardexchange.net/index.php?gamepage-appid-570)

## Most Steam seasonal sales have:

- A theoretical max of **∞** levels for the regular badge.
- A theoretical max of **∞** level for the Foil badge.

All Steam seasonal sales so far with **∞** badge levels:

- [Steam Summer Adventure 2014](http://www.steamcardexchange.net/index.php?gamepage-appid-303700)
- [Monster Summer Game](http://www.steamcardexchange.net/index.php?gamepage-appid-368020)
- [Holiday Sale 2013](http://www.steamcardexchange.net/index.php?gamepage-appid-267420)
- [Holiday Sale 2014](http://www.steamcardexchange.net/index.php?gamepage-appid-335590)

The Steam Winter Sale of 2013 was the first to set the precedent, in which for the first time both foil and regular badges were able to level up as many times possible during the event.  This meant that users could easily complete badges and quickly level up their Steam accounts, without a "level cap" on the badge.

A few examples of [users](http://steamcommunity.com/id/palmdesert/badges/) with high levels of badges:
[image]

From the Steam Winter Sale on out, most of the other Steam seasonal sales feature badges unlimited levels (exception is the Summer Getaway Sale), so theoretically, there's no limit to how many levels you can get with any of those badges.

Comment: Is this foil badge a separate thing or does is somehow interfere with the normal badge levels?

Comment: Foil badges are separate.

Comment: Actually [bUm805](http://steamcommunity.com/id/bUm805/gamecards/267420/) has a much higher level non-foil holiday sale badge. level 2013

Answer (score 27):

From [the FAQ](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq):

> #### Can I upgrade my game badge?
>
> If you gather another complete set of trading cards you can upgrade that game badge. You can craft a set for a game **at most five times**. Each time you upgrade the game badge you'll get an extra 100XP, as well as upgrading the image and title of the badge.

You can also build a foil game badge out of foil cards. That badge, however, cannot be upgraded.

Comment: Ah, I must have missed that! Don't suppose there's a guide to all the badges somewhere?

Comment: What should there be a guide for? Don't you just need to collect all cards and then craft a badge?

Comment: I meant a list of all the badge images for each level/game, just interested in what they all look like.

Comment: @Ric You can check the [steam market for game cards](http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=game+card) to see some cards, then stalk the sellers' profiles to see their badges...

Comment: @Ric You can use http://www.steamcardexchange.net/; it's got every game listed with all badges, emoticons, backgrounds, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can see all badges, cards and rewards on [Steam Card Exchange](http://www.steamcardexchange.net/index.php?showcase).

As mentioned before for most games the maximum badge level is 5 and the maximum foil badge level is 1. The Winter Sale of 2013 introduced a badge with a maximum level of 1000.

PalmDessert is as far as I know the user with the highest level, at a whopping (currently) 260.

Comment: And PalmDesert was the first user to hit level 500 as well