# How many times do I need to collect sets of Steam Trading cards?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I managed to craft the Team Fortress 2 badge after trading away a couple of duplicates to friends. However when I went to view my badge progress, I noticed that the remaining duplicate cards had formed an alliance and were requesting more of their friends for another badge.

Just how many levels are there for card badges?

Comment: Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118118/how-many-levels-are-there-for-steam-trading-card-badges?rq=1

Comment: thanks @John, that didn't come up when I searched, nor as a suggestion when writing the question

Comment: Really? That's odd. It showed up as the first related question for me. (Maybe those lists don't populate until the question gets posted)

Comment: @RavenDreamer - in any case, next time i'll search harder :)